# SQL - Coalesce until next available date

Tags: sql, join, coalesce

Hopefully simple enough but cannot find the answer. Trying to run:

SQL Server

```
left outer join exchanges fx (nolock) on 
v1.ccy = fx.ccy and v1.date = fx.date
```

The problem is that fx.ccy may not exist on fx.date. I would therefore like to join on the next available date.

Many thanks,

José

Comment: What do you mean by "next available date"?

Comment: What database? Postgres? Oracle? SQLServer?

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and your full query.

Comment: If v1.date is '31 January 2014' then I would want the next available date after '31 January 2014'. SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
....
left outer join exchanges fx (nolock) on 
v1.ccy = fx.ccy and fx.date = (
    select min(date) from exchanges where date >= v1.date and ccy = v1.ccy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
left outer join exchanges fx (nolock) on 
v1.ccy = fx.ccy and fx.date = (select min(date) 
                                 from exchanges x 
                                where v1.ccy = x.ccy 
                                  and x.date >= v1.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
left outer join exchanges fx (nolock) on
v1.ccy = fx.ccy and 
(select min(date) from exchanges (nolock) where date >= v1.date and ccy = v1.ccy) = fx.date
```

Thank you for your help.

José